# Implicit grant type: Invalid grant_type parameter value WSO2

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2

I try generate a access token in my application on WSO2 using implicit grant type, following the request:

```
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8243
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: d6ef6038-9860-bdc6-3867-70af98b37cc6

grant_type=code&response_type=implicit&client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fplayground%2Foauth2client&scope=default
```

And the request return this error:

```
{
    "error_description": "Invalid grant_type parameter value",
    "error": "invalid_request"
}
```

This is my grant types settings:

[Grant Types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDcHO.png)

Why this error happen, although the settings include the implicit grant type?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing up few things. If you want to use the [Implicit grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-31), you don't use the `/token` endpoint - you get everything from the authorization endpoint. The request could look like this:

```
/auth?response_type=token&client_id=...&redirect_uri=...
```

and after a successful authentication, the client gets an access token right away as part of the redirect URL.

If you have a code and you want to exchange it for an access token and a refresh token, you are using the [Authorization code grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-24). Then the correct `grant_type` value is `authorization_code` and you must specify the code in the `code` URL parameter. So the error message you are getting is correct.

Finally, the `token` endpoint has no `response_type` parameter. It's a parameter of the authrization endpoint and the correct value for the implicit flow is `token`, because you want an access token to be returned.

Comment: It's work! You are right. I use /auth endpoint with response_type how token and redirect_uri is the same I set on my application callback.